# Level curves representable by real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, economics

**EDIT:** **I incorrectly interpreted the original question. The bounty has been awarded based on the (incorrect) interpretation I wrote here. The final version is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432644/can-a-level-curve-of-a-function-given-with-certain-properties-be-discontinuous).**

---

Consider the function $u : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that the following properties are satisfied:

1. Every level curve is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. (That is, a level curve $U(x,y)= c$ can be written as $y = f(x)$ for some $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.)
2. $\forall$ $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$, the sets $L(p)$ and $U(p)$ are closed. (Definition below.)

**Definition:** For $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$, define the lower contour of $p$ as $L(p) := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : u(x,y) \leq u(p)\}$ and the upper contour of $p$ as $U(p) := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : u(x,y) \geq u(p)\}$.

**Question:** Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$. Given $u(\cdot, \cdot)$ such that one of the level curves $y = f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = t$, construct (or show the existence of) two points $p, l \in X$ such that $l$ is a limit point of both $L(p)$ and $U(p)$ but is contained in exactly one of the two (contour sets). (The other level curves may or may not be discontinuous.)

---

I posted a question on Economics SE that I could solve only partially. This is essentially the same question presented in a different manner. Here's the original question:

> Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose $\succeq$ denotes a continuous preference relation. If every indifference curve can be represented by functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, will it mean the ICs will be continuous functions?

If you want to see my attempt (and/or post an answer), please [click on this](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/51103/indifference-curves-representable-by-real-valued-functions-on-mathbbr-of-a).

Comment: Do we know that $u$ is continuous?  Differentiable?  What do you mean that the level curve is discontinuous?  Do you mean disconnected instead?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe We don't assume continuity (or differentiability) of $u$. Since each level curve $\mathcal{C}$ can be represented by a function $f_{\mathcal{C}} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, it's the discontinuity of $f_\mathcal{C}$ that I am talking about. (To give an example, a level curve can't be a circle on the 2D plane; it could be something like $y = x + 2$ or even something *pathological* like the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit : I claimed something false, the following is wrong.]

The fact that $L(p)$ and $U(p)$ are closed implies that the function $f$ associated with $c = u(p)$ is continuous. Indeed, if $f$ is such that $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, u(x, y) = u(p) \} = \{ (x, f(x)), x \in \mathbb{R} \}$, you can write : *[the next equality is false]*

$$ L(p) = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, y \leq f(x) \} $$

and $L(p)$ is closed if and only if $f$ is upper-semicontinuous. (This is a well-known property of upper-semicontinuous functions : see for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity).)

Now, the same reasoning with $U(p)$ implies that $f$ is also lower-semicontinuous. Therefore, $f$ is actually continuous. (I think this proves the claim you quote ?)

EDIT : Second attempt : If $l \in X$ is a limit point of both $L(p)$ and $U(p)$, since both sets are closed, you have $l \in L(p)$ and $l \in U(p)$. Therefore (and this is actually independant of the continuity of level functions $f$) you cannot find an $l$ as in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why does $L(p)$ and $U(p)$ being closed imply $f$ is continuous? I'll give you a counter-example: Consider $f := g \circ h$ where $g$ is discontinuous and strictly monotonous and $h$ is continuous. (Since $g$ is discontinuous and $h$ is continuous, their composition $f$ will be discontinuous.) For all $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we have $L_{h}(p)$ and $U_{h}(p)$ closed. Since $(g \circ h) (x,y) \leq (g \circ h) (p) \iff h(x,y) \leq h(p)$, the set $L_{f := g \circ h}(p) = L_{h}(p)$ will also be closed. Repeat the same argument for $U_{f}(p)$.

Comment: The preference (or the binary relation associated with the function $u$) is continuous when the upper/lower contours of every point $p \in X$ (where $X$ is the domain) are closed. [Here's a proof if you want to check out](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/18222/33107).

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake in my reasoning, sorry.

Comment: As for your second attempt: We are given $u$ that satisfies the two properties. But we don't know for sure if $u$ actually can satisfy the two properties simultaneously. If such $u$ does not exist in the first place, then the next part (that is, a limit point can lie only in one of the two unique disjoint closed sets) does not make sense I think. What I mean is, if we are to show $A \implies B$, then if $A$ is a false statement, $\neg A \lor B$ for false $A$ will (trivially) come as true, right?

Comment: I have modified the question slightly to avoid the confusion. Sorry if it was not clear earlier.

Comment: I think something is unclear : you speak about disjoint closed sets, but $L(p)$ and $U(p)$ are not disjoint ($p$ is an element of both) ?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Please ignore that then. That can be replaced by "two unique closed sets disjoint without the boundary", but that is unnecessary. Further, my $A$ was false initially and you proved what you had to. I'll modify this question back to the previous one, write a new question, award you the bounty (because it was my fault) and I hope you (and others) give the final (hopefully, correct) question a thought. Please see the updated question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432644/can-a-level-curve-of-a-function-given-with-certain-properties-be-discontinuous.