# Can a level curve of a function (given) with certain properties be discontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, economics

Consider the function $u : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that the following properties are satisfied:

1. Every level curve is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. (That is, a level curve $U(x,y)= c$ can be written as $y = f(x)$ for some $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.)
2. $\forall$ $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$, the sets $L(p)$ and $U(p)$ are closed. (Definition below.)

**Definition:** For $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$, define the lower contour of $p$ as $L(p) := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : u(x,y) \leq u(p)\}$ and the upper contour of $p$ as $U(p) := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : u(x,y) \geq u(p)\}$.

**Question:** Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$. Given $u(\cdot, \cdot)$, can $u$ have a level curve $y = f(x)$ such that $f$ is discontinuous?

---

I posted this question originally on Economics SE that I could solve only partially. This is essentially the same question without the mention of preference (or the binary relation). Here's the original question:

> Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose $\succeq$ denotes a continuous preference relation. If every indifference curve can be represented by functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, will it mean the ICs will (necessarily) be continuous functions?

If you want to see my attempt (and/or post an answer), please [click on this](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/51103/indifference-curves-representable-by-real-valued-functions-on-mathbbr-of-a).

Answer (score 2):

I think I have figured it out. Here's my new attempt :

Assume that there exists some $p = (x_0, y_0)$, $t = u(x_0, y_0)$, $f$ being the IC of $u = t$, such that $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$. You can find $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to x_0$, and $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $y_0$.

Up to extracting a subsequence, you can assume that $f(x_n)$ converges to some element in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ +\infty, -\infty \}$. Denote this limit by $y'$.

If $y'$ is finite, since $(x_n, f(x_n))$ are in both $L(p)$ and $U(p)$ and these sets are closed, $(x_0, y')$ as well, and therefore $u(x_0, y') = u(x_0, y_0)$. But $y_0 \neq y'$ and the level set is represented by $f$, this is a contradiction.

Now change your point of view and consider, at fixed $x$, the values taken by $u(x, y)$ when $y$ varies, $x$ is fixed. $y \mapsto u(x, y)$ is injective by the fact that each level set can be represented by a function. It is even bijective since, for each $c$, there exists $f_c$ and $y = f_c(x)$ such that $u(x, y) = c$. Furthermore, $\{ y, u(x,y) \geq u(x, a) \}$ is closed for each fixed $a$, $x$, so the sets $\{ y, u(x, y) \geq c \}$ are closed for every fixed $c$, $x$. The same holds if you reverse the inequality, so $y \mapsto u(x, y)$ is continuous for each $x$. Being bijective, it is a monotone map.

Let's return to $y'$ when it is infinite and assume, for instance, $y' = +\infty$ (up to a symmetry on the whole plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can always assume $y' = +\infty$). For each $n$, $y \mapsto u(x_n, y)$ is either increasing or decreasing : but, since there are either infinitely many $n$ such that it is increasing or infinitely many such that it is decreasing, you may assume up to extracting a subsequence that they are all increasing or all decreasing. Likewise, $y \mapsto u(x_0, y)$ is also either increasing or decreasing.

For $n$ large enough, $f(x_n) > y_0+1$ and thus $(x_n, y_0-1)$ and $(x_n, y_0+1)$ are both elements of $U(p)$ or $L(p)$ (depending on whether $y \mapsto u(x_n, y)$ are increasing or decreasing). Both sets are closed, so $(x_0, y_0+1)$ and $(x_0, y_0-1)$ are both elements of the corresponding set. But this contradicts the (strict) monotonicity of $y \mapsto u(x_0, y)$, since we know the value $u(x_0, y_0)$.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being late. I'll read this today (hopefully, by the next 12 hours) and let you know my thoughts about it. I'm not accepting it right now because if your answer is not convincing which I hope is not the case, then I'll be closing the window to invite other answers. Thank you.